# access selector inside tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to access specific `td` in `toboady` using `JQuery` and change the text value but when i do that. all the other `td`s in every `tr` with the same `class` name is changed which is not correct because each tr have different `class`

here is my html code :

```
<tbody>
<tr class="paymentline" data-cid="c10">
    <td class="col-tendered">
        33.00
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="paymentline selected">
    <td class="col-tendered edit">
        33.00
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is my `JQuery` code :

```
$('.paymentline.selected .edit').text(parseFloat(this.getAmount(updated_sale_price)).toFixed(2));
```

when my i run my `JQuery` code all the `td`s with `.edit` class will be changed.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Your code selects all input fields with the class `edit`, that are inside a parent element that has the class `paymentline` and `selected`. If that is not what you want, then you need to find a more specific selector.

Comment: it change all the td s with class edit and i want only the td in the selected calss tr..do you get me ?!

Comment: @Mostafa Mohamed seems to work fine when it's only a background color change. try looking in the parsing area rather than the selector. https://jsfiddle.net/rkkgu1p9/1/

Comment: that comment helped me more than the answers to figure out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<table>
        <tbody>
<tr class="paymentline" data-cid="c10">
    <td class="col-tendered">
        33.00
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="paymentline selected">
    <td class="col-tendered edit">
        33.00
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="paymentline">
    <td class="col-tendered edit">
        33.00
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('.selected .edit').text(parseFloat(this.getAmount(updated_sale_price)).toFixed(2));
```

This code is working for me

Comment: tried that and not working. it will changes every td with edit calss !

Comment: Thanks my friend that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add `table` in the selector:

```
$('table .paymentline.selected .edit')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/spdv4ab0/

Comment: Thanks my friend that's helpful